# Was Old English "ēalās" equivalent to Modern English "hello"?

Tags: meaning, old-english, interjections

In a [question in the Spanish Language site](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/21694/12637) about the origin of Spanish *hola* 'hello', [one of the answers](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/31141/12637) states that Old English *ēalās*, written *ēalā* before a name, already sounded quite similar to *hola*, and was used as an equivalent to our current *hello*. The user states that *ēalā freond* means *hello friend*. But the only example I can find of those words is in [the Wessex Gospels](http://textusreceptusbibles.com/Wessex/40/26):

> Ða cwæð se hælend to hym. **Eala freond** to hwam be-come þu. Ða geneahlacten hyo & þanne hælend ge-namen.

This is from [Matthew 25, 50](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Mateo%2026%3A50&version=ASV):

> And Jesus said unto him, Friend, *do* that for which thou art come. Then they came and laid hands on Jesus, and took him.

Given the context, I would say that *ēalās* means something closer to the current *alas*, and not *hello*. In fact, *ēalās* and *alas* are much more similar than *ēalās* and *hola*.

Etymonline actually [states that](https://www.etymonline.com/word/hello) Modern English *hello* comes from *hallo*, an aliteration of *[holla](https://www.etymonline.com/word/holla)*, which came from French *holà* (akin to Spanish *hola*) and does not refer to *ēalās*. In the same web, the only reference to *eala* from Old English is in the [entry for *oh*](https://www.etymonline.com/word/oh).

So, did Old English *ēalās* mean *hello*? Or was it used as the current *alas*? Or did it mean something completely different?

Comment: Stephen Fry does an interesting podcast on the origin of hello. He thinks it comes via the hunting fields.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*Eala* could be a vocative, but it wasn't a standalone greeting like *hello* functions now.

I am not familiar with *eala* being used as a greeting in Old English. According to the Bosworth-Toller Dictionary, *[eala](http://www.bosworthtoller.com/008383)* was an interjection that could sometimes be translated *O* and sometimes *alas*. I have mostly seen it in that context. Very occasionally *eala(s)* could be *ale* ([BT entry](http://www.bosworthtoller.com/008382)) or *temple* ([BT entry](http://www.bosworthtoller.com/008481); the nominative is *ealh*, and the [Old English Translator](https://www.oldenglishtranslator.co.uk/) shows *ealas* as the nominative/genitive accusative).

In the scholarship I've found, *eala* is treated as an interjection often used with the vocative.

Beechy, Tiffany. “Eala Earendel: Extraordinary Poetics in Old English.” Modern Philology, vol. 108, no. 1, 2010, pp. 1–19. JSTOR, www.jstor.org/stable/10.1086/656221.

- Beechy focuses on parsing *earendel*; *eala* is treated as a translation of *O*, i.e. *O oriens* ~ *eala earendel*. (O Dawn!)

Clayton, Mary. “The Old English ‘Promissio Regis.’” Anglo-Saxon England, vol. 37, 2008, pp. 91–150. JSTOR, www.jstor.org/stable/44510974.

- Clayton treats *eala* as an introduction to address in the phrases *eola leof hlaford* and *eola leofan men*;  *O dear lord* or *O dear men*. However, I get no sense of greeting, and Clayton never distinguishes a meaning like *alas* or *O* from a meaning like *hello*.

Hiltunen, Risto. "*Eala, geferan and gode wyrhtan*": On Interjections in Old English." *Inside Old English: Essays in Honour of Bruce Mitchell*. Wiley, 2006. https://books.google.com/books?id=W1l_BwAAQBAJ&lpg=PA99&ots=NwzCdHvJwY&dq=%22eala%20leofan%20men%22&pg=PA96#v=onepage&q&f=false.

- Hiltunen analyzes a few interjections in Old English. *Eala* often initiates an address, especially when followed by noun phrases in a vocative case. Towards the end of a section on *eala* on p. 100, Hiltunen says this: "Both materials (Offerberg's study of interjections and the Helsinki Corpus) indicate the importance of *eala* for signalling audience attention to the message being conveyed." *Signalling audience attention* is more of a rhetorical move in sermons or homilies than a greeting.

So the issue here is that *eala*, at least in the texts we have, isn't like saying *hello* (e.g. *Wes hāl*). It's not a greeting. It is not even necessarily a lament, as *alas* has become in English. As far as I know, it does not even function alone as *hello* does. ("Hello!") It is a call to attention.

Comment: So it's more of a "Hey" or a "yo!" ?